# apache xampp proxy pass for certain urls

Tags: apache

In `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests Off
 ServerName localhost
 ProxyPassMatch /sbl_next/?$ http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
 ProxyPassReverse /sbl_next/?$ http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
</VirtualHost>
```

I have these lines and as per this, I get redirected to port 3000 for home page and otherwise to port `80` Now, for some other url's like 
`http://localhost:80/sbl_next/abc`, I want it to redirect to port http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/abc . How do I do it?

Comment: With "I get redirected" you probably mean that your request will get proxied to that internal URL? Because I do not see any real redirection in this...

Comment: @arkascha: Yeah, That's what I meant. But it works just fine. It works onlt for the home page though

Comment: You can remove the line end anchor from your expression, that that _all_ URLs under `/sbl_next` will get proxied. If you want only _some_ of those to get fully proxied, whilst others should point to that internal base URL, then you have to tell the rules for that in your question.

Comment: @arkascha: Thanks. Like I said, for /abc, I would need that redirected to port 3000/abc.How do I get that to work?

Comment: You did not really answer my question above, so I posted an answer with two approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I will post two examples to demonstrate what I asked about in the comments:

The first option is actually a bit simplified compared to your example:

ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPass /sbl_next http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
  ProxyPassReverse /sbl_next http://localhost:3000/sbl_next

This proxies all requests to any URL *below* that base URL you match, so for example:

- /sbl_next => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
- /sbl_next/ => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/
- /sbl_next/foo => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/foo
- /sbl_next/foo/bar => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/foo/bar
- /sbl_next/foo?bar=1 => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/foo?bar=1

---

This version defines "exceptios" from the general proxy rule which is what you *might* try to express in your question (that is vague and you did not answer my question about that):

ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName localhost
  ProxyPassMatch /sbl_next/foo$ http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/bar
  ProxyPassMatch /sbl_next/foo http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/baz
  ProxyPassMatch /sbl_next/?$ http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
  ProxyPass /sbl_next http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
  ProxyPassReverse /sbl_next http://localhost:3000/sbl_next

Besides the "general" proxy rule at the bottom this defines "exceptions" above:

- /sbl_next/foo => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/bar
- /sbl_next/foo/bar => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/baz
- /sbl_next => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
- /sbl_next/ => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next/
- /sbl_next/bar => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next
- /sbl_next/bar?baz=1 => http://localhost:3000/sbl_next?baz=1